# My video file is not recognized by next.js done with typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I ran into a problem in my project which is done in next.js, typescript, tailwindcss. I am making my Masthead for the website and I want the background to be a video. For some reason, the video is not being recognized, I tried putting it into different directories, importing `import Background "./material-bg.mp4"` and even converting the file from mp4 to webm because originally it was an mp4 file. I tried if only this specific video is not being recognized, which is true when I used a jpg, but not if it was a video. I think there is a problem recognizing videos themselves because it didn't recognize other videos as well. Thank you so much in advance!

```
<video autoPlay loop muted playsInline className='absolute w-full h-full object-cover'>
            <source src="./material-bg.webm" type='video/webm; codecs=vp9'/>
        </video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [next.js docs:](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving)

> Next.js can serve static files, like images, under a folder called public in the root directory. Files inside public can then be referenced by your code starting from the base URL (/).

So, create a folder named as `public` in the root directory of your project, put your static files inside this folder, in your case the video file, so just keep the `src` path as it is and it should work now.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! It worked!